# How to understand "As though he needs reminding of that on his first day at school." in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "Never mind that, do you think he remembers what You-Know-Who looks like?"
>
> Their mother suddenly became very stern.
>
> "I forbid you to ask him, Fred. No, don't you dare. **As though he needs reminding of that on his first day at school**."

This is from the book Harry Potter. I had a hard time to understand the sentence in bold above.

1. "**As though**" looks strange.
2. The usage of "**reminding of**" is unusual and it's typically used as "**reminding sb. of sth.**".
3. It looks like a incomplete sentence and there seems something that has been dropped.

Can someone help me to understand the sentence?

Comment: The reference is to a variety of teen-speak in California where **as if** means "How could anyone in their right mind think that!"  which is pretty much what **as though** means in your quote above.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence has a small part omitted from it, like '*it looks*':

> (Due to Fred's expressed intention) ***it looks* as though** (= as if) **he**
>   **needs reminding of that...**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-if-and-as-though

In other words: '**One could think he needs**...'

'**Reminding of that**' doesn't differ much from '**reminding sb. of sth.**' since the missing '**sb.**' is mentioned as '**he**' (**he** needs + the noun phrase '**reminding of that**').

Comment: So Fred's mother is saying: he(Harry) need be reminded of that on his first day at school. Is that right? On the other hand, what's "that" referring to exactly?

Comment: No, he _doesn't_ need it, but Fred behaves _as if_ Harry needed reminding of that thing.

Comment: The mother is saying that he should certainly NOT be reminded of it. The phrase **as though** is a kind of reprimand there. It is similar to *How could you think such a thing!?*

Comment: I suggest editing this answer to replace "it looks" with "you are speaking" or something like that. In my opinion, "it looks" doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the sentence is an incomplete sentence, or sentence fragment. A complete-sentence version of what Fred's mother is saying would be:

> You are speaking as though he needs reminding of that on his first day at school.

Her point is that Fred *should not* remind Harry about You-Know-Who on Harry's first day of school.

[Alex_ander's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/181639/2020) states that another way to complete the sentence would be "It looks as though he needs reminding of that on his first day at school". In my opinion, this is *not* a good way to complete the sentence, because Fred's mother wouldn't say that unless she *actually believed* that Harry needed reminding.